# Adding header to a specific column using awk

Tags: shell, command-line

A new born, no name Column! located in the middle of named columns. It needs a header without disturbing the file order.

I splitted the first column of a big file in two, so, the second (new) column has stayed without any header. I tried to do through 'awk' and 'sed' but I failed to perform it without messing up the file's order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a tab delimiter:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} 
      NR==1 {$2 = "NewHeader" FS $2; print; next}
      {print;}'
```

`BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"}` sets the input and output delimiter to tab, instead of the default space. Change "\t" to your delimiter if its not tab.

`NR==1{}` says to execute the actions only on the first line

`{$2 = "NewHeader" FS $2; print; next}` says set your second field on the first line to "NewHeader" then a field sep, then the old value. This adds a column just to that row.  We then print the modified line, and move on.

`{print;}` applies to the rest of the lines and prints them unmodified.

e.g.

```
$ cat awk.txt
col1    col2    col3
val1    val2    val3    val4
val11   val22   val33   val44
val111  val222  val333  val444
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"}
>       NR==1 {$2 = "NewHeader" FS $2; print; next}
>       {print;}' awk.txt
col1    NewHeader       col2    col3
val1    val2    val3    val4
val11   val22   val33   val44
val111  val222  val333  val444
```

Sed could do this as well.  If you know your column name, something as simple as this would work:

```
sed '1 s/^col1\t/col1\tNewHeader\t/g' awk.txt
col1    NewHeader       col2    col3
val1    val2    val3    val4
val11   val22   val33   val44
val111  val222  val333  val444
```

For the first line, this matches the beginning of the line, your column header, and a tab, and replaces it with the same string, then a new header and another tab.

The more generalized case is below, capturing the first column value, then printing it back out along with the new header and a tab.

```
$ sed '1 s/\(^[^\t]*[\t]\)/\1NewHeader\t/g' awk.txt
col1    NewHeader       col2    col3
val1    val2    val3    val4
val11   val22   val33   val44
val111  val222  val333  val444
```